# How do I zip a SQL Server backup file using Powershell and save in the same directory?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to zip up a SQL Server backup file and save it in the same directory using PowerShell. The only way it works for me is if I move it to a temp folder then zip it up and move it back to the original folder.  But I don't want to move it.  I just want to keep it in the existing folder and ignore all other files in the folder. The zip file name should be the same name as the backup file with extension as .zip and it doesn't need to be in a folder.

Here is my code (which I would like to change)

```
#Backup SQL database
Backup-SqlDatabase -Database Mydbname -ServerInstance MyServerName-   BackupSetName "Mydbname-Full Database Backup" -DatabaseFile Mydbname.bak -ExpirationDate 0 -Initialize

#Move backup to temp location and Zip the folder
$temppath = "C:\Temp\Bkup"
$sourcepath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Mydbname.bak"
$destpath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\"
Move-Item -Path $sourcepath -Destination $temppath
Compress-Archive -Path $temppath -DestinationPath\Mydbname.bak.zip
```

Is there a way to streamline this code so that it doesn't create a new folder?
Note: If I run the script twice, it will fail the second time around because I still have the moved file in the temp folder.  Is there a way to delete the file from the temp location after moving it back to the original folder. (I am new to PowerShell.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your source is one file, try this.  Compress archive can take a source as a single file.  I commented out 2 of the lines.

```
$sourcepath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Mydbname.bak"
$destpath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\"
Compress-Archive -Path $sourcepath -DestinationPath\Mydbname.bak.zip
```

Comment: Thanks @Ctznkane525.  How do I check if the zip file already exists and dropping it prior to compressing it (otherwise it will fail the second time round)?

Comment: you can use the remove-item cmdlet.  Might I recommend you date these files instead, so you can save more than one.  Set it up so you can the zips around for x amount of days.